# How to pass a file (contents) from an Angular 5 app to a C# .NET Web Api 2?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

So I have an Angular 5 app with an Angular Material data table. When a user clicks on "comments" a dialog pops up where user can see some data from the row he selected & type in some comments & upload a file. When clicking save, some contents of that dialog should be sent to my C# .NET Web Api 2. How can I do this? So far I've got the following:

Dialog component HTML:

```
<div>
    <label for="file-input">Comments File: </label>
    <input #fileToUpload id="file-input" type="file" [(ngModel)]="EADModal.commentsFile">
  </div>
```

Dialog component TS (relevant part):

```
fileToUpload;

@ViewChild('fileToUpload') set setFileToUpload(fileToUpload: ElementRef) {
    this.fileToUpload = fileToUpload;
  }  

save() {
    // Some data has been removed for this code sample
    const json: any = {
      'Tenant': '',
      'Username': '',
      'Password': '',
      'SC_title': '',
      'SC_siteRelativeUrl': '',
      'L_title': '',
      'DS_subsequentFolderNames': [
        ...
      ],
      'File': this.fileToUpload.nativeElement.files[0]
    };

    const postModalDataSubscribe = this.tableService.postModalData(json).subscribe(res => {
      console.log('modal data posted success!');
    });
    this.modalRef.close();
```

The `this.fileToUpload` variable will containt the element reference to the  input HTML element. `this.fileToUpload.nativeElement.files[0]` will contain my file, as seen here in dev tools:

[image]

Then I pass the object, with the file to my service, seen here:

```
public postModalData(jsonStringified: string) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:49836/listitem/CreateListItemSubsequentFolders', jsonStringified, httpOptionsWithCredentials);
  }
```

This eventually comes into my API (running on localhost for now), code seen here:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("listItem/CreateListItemSubsequentFolders")]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateListItemSubsequentFolders([FromBody] ListItemForm data)
    {
         ....
    }
```

Now, when I see what is in `data`, I can see all my other properties (tenant, username, password, etc.) being in `data`, so in my code, I can do

```
var test = data.Tenant;
```

The "test" variable will contain a value, the value from my front-end json 'Tenant' property. Now I want the same to happen for my `data.File`. How can I get the file in my data object so that I can write code with it and pass that file to a back-end service to upload it somewhere (using MemoryStreams, not saving it locally & uploading it that way)?.

Does anyone know what I need to change so that I can get my file (contents) in my API/data object so that I can pass it to a back-end service?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `formData` to upload files.

```
const formData = new FormData();

    // add the files
formData.append('file', file));  // this.fileToUpload.nativeElement.files[0]

    // you can add json data to form data if you want.
formData.append('data', jsonData , {type: 'application/json'}));

this.http.post<ResponseInterface>(this.apiUrl, formData);
```

Comment: Hi, this does not yet have desired effect in my API. Is it because my mapping to data.File isn't correct? Right now It's a byte[], what should it be?